# SQL Join between multiple tables

Tags: sql, join

I'm banging my head against the wall now. I've used many hours and am half way but given up on the last part of my query.

I have three tables.

1. `R8` table  (this table has information about machines)
2. `Actor` table (This is the customer, vendor and person table)
3. `TXT` table (This table has the text value for some fields in R8 and Actor tables)

The result I want is:

R8.gr, R8.gr1, r8.gr2 are linked to TXT. For instance r8.gr2 = txt.txtno from where I can extract the text value for grx. This problem I have solved.

But in the same result I want to have r8.custno.grx.txt meaning that i first have to look up for the custno in the Actor table and then find the grx field and look for the txt for this grX field in the TXT table.

Here is my SQL query that gives me the first part:

```
SELECT      
    maskin.RNo, maskin.Nm, maskin.Gr5, tekst.Txt AS 'Produksjonsår',
    maskin.Gr7, tekst2.Txt AS 'Strøm', maskin.Gr8, 
    tekst3.Txt AS 'Eierforhold', maskin.Gr3, tekst4.Txt AS 'Båndtype'
FROM            
    R8 AS maskin 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Txt AS tekst3 ON maskin.Gr8 = tekst3.TxtNo AND tekst3.TxtTp = 93 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Txt AS tekst4 ON maskin.Gr3 = tekst4.TxtNo AND tekst4.TxtTp = 38 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Txt AS tekst2 ON maskin.Gr7 = tekst2.TxtNo AND tekst2.TxtTp = 20 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Txt AS tekst ON maskin.Gr5 = tekst.TxtNo AND tekst.TxtTp = 40
```

What I need suggestions/help for is to get the txt for custno(from r8) -> gr(from actor) -> txt (from txt)

Comment: Which columns are the keys for each table, and which are the data you want?

Comment: The last two columns I want are TXT from the txt table. Custno is a key in the table R8 which is the one I want to lookup for in the table Actor. Then from the table actor where r8.custno = actor.custno i want to go get actor.gr = txt.txtno to get the desired txt.txt value. I hope I explained good enough ...

Comment: Paste `create table` and `insert` statements and the output you want into your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're asking for. I added the 2nd and 3rd joins to your query and the field you're looking for in the txt.

```
SELECT      
    maskin.RNo, maskin.Nm, maskin.Gr5, tekst.Txt AS 'Produksjonsår',
    maskin.Gr7, tekst2.Txt AS 'Strøm', maskin.Gr8, 
    tekst3.Txt AS 'Eierforhold', maskin.Gr3, tekst4.Txt AS 'Båndtype',
    myTxt.Txt
FROM            
    R8 AS maskin 
LEFT JOIN 
    Actor on maskin.CustNo = Actor.CustNo
LEFT JOIN 
    Txt AS myTxt On txt.myTxt = Actor.gr
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Txt AS tekst3 ON maskin.Gr8 = tekst3.TxtNo AND tekst3.TxtTp = 93 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Txt AS tekst4 ON maskin.Gr3 = tekst4.TxtNo AND tekst4.TxtTp = 38 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Txt AS tekst2 ON maskin.Gr7 = tekst2.TxtNo AND tekst2.TxtTp = 20 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Txt AS tekst ON maskin.Gr5 = tekst.TxtNo AND tekst.TxtTp = 40
```